# Looking for a command that will return the proc, func, etc that uses another proc, func, etc

Tags: script, grep, regex, awk

Grep-ing for a function name to see where it's being used returns a list of rows and row numbers. Is there a smart way of using grep and awk to get the name of the calling procedure instead?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by name of the calling procedure?

Comment: When you find the file with the name you are looking for and you open it, you have to scroll up to find the procedure that calls it. I am using vi so the option of an IDE isn't a choice.

Comment: I mean, for example, you are looking for instances of a function called "foo()" in all files in a tree. The calling procedure/function would be the function that uses foo(), or that has foo() as part of its definition.

Comment: The aim of this is after finding the line that the function call appears in, to find the context in which it's being used.

Comment: See <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563616/vim-and-ctags-tips-and-tricks>, <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900450/vim-command-to-find-all-function-names-that-contain-a-string-in-their-bodies-in>.

Answer (score 2):

For jumping to the definition of an identifier: **Exuberant Ctags**

http://ctags.sourceforge.net/

For finding uses of an identifier: **GNU ID-Utils** (mkid indexer, lid query command)

http://www.gnu.org/software/idutils/

Comment: ctags also has hotkey support in vim at least (and I'm sure other editors) to quickly jump to function definitions while coding.